# Finding all Subconnected Subgraphs from a neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

After trying doing it in multiple and looking everywhere online to find related problems unsuccesfully ,  iv'e decided to ask here - i hope you can help .

My issue is this -> i am trying to find all the unconnected subgraphs in a neo4j db.  The main problem here is , that traversing in a single direction from a given node in a connected set, wouldn't allways traverse all the nodes in the connected set -> it would only traverse the ones in a certain direction in a query like this:

```
match (a:TempNode)-[r*]->(n)
where NOT (a)<-[:LINKED|LINKED2]-(:TempNode)
return distinct(a.Lineage+collect(distinct(n.Lineage)))
```

(assuming the second 'Where' condition is the supposed 'starting' node for sets).

The problem is , that my graph is populated with connected sets like the following :
[Conncted set Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loatQ.png)

and so, as you can see , it has many nodes with inconsistent edge directions between them .

Running an undirected query like :

```
match (a:MetasetFeature)-[r*]-(n)
return a,collect(distinct(n))
```

Might work if i put in a filter to get some specific set , but i cant put filters inside , as i want ALL my subconnected sets,  and that will run forever, and i have ~2000 of those sets , with an amount of nodes of ~40000 .

Any advice how can i achieve a solution to this problem efficiently ?

I am trying to think of a way to create a new graph from the existing one , in which all sets would start from one node ( the one with the minimal id for example ) and would have only a single direction until the node with the highest id , which in essense means creating an ordered set out of each subconnected group but couldn't achieve it  .

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !

*EDIT : Never mind , solved it :) .

Used the Apoc Procedures (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases)

To get access to the traversal API , and used it to solve the problem using this query if someone else needs it :

```
MATCH (cs:SomeLabel)-[:LINKED]->(:SomeLabel)
where NOT (cs)<-[:LINKED]-(:SomeLabel)
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(cs,       {relationshipFilter:"LINKED",uniqueness:"NODE_GLOBAL",bfs:false}) YIELD path
WITH cs.Lineage as source, path 
unwind extract(x in nodes(path) | x.Lineage) as node
with source, collect(distinct(node)) as set 
unwind set as setMember
with source,setMember
order by setMember
with source,collect(setMember) as orderedSet
return distinct(orderedSet)
```

Comment: Never mind , solved it :)

Comment: Looks like a good solution! To close out this question, could you copy and paste the solution to an answer and accept it? That way if your question comes up as a related question to someone else, it will have a clear indication that the question has been answered. If left alone, links to it (such as in the list of related question to the right) make it seem like an unanswered question with no given answers.

Comment: sure :) posted the answer

Comment: Great! Make sure to accept your answer too (the checkmark below the score)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the Apoc Procedures (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases)

To get access to the traversal API , and used it to solve the problem using this query if someone else needs it :

```
MATCH (cs:SomeLabel)-[:LINKED]->(:SomeLabel)
where NOT (cs)<-[:LINKED]-(:SomeLabel)
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(cs,       {relationshipFilter:"LINKED",uniqueness:"NODE_GLOBAL",bfs:false}) YIELD path
WITH cs.Lineage as source, path 
unwind extract(x in nodes(path) | x.Lineage) as node
with source, collect(distinct(node)) as set 
unwind set as setMember
with source,setMember
order by setMember
with source,collect(setMember) as orderedSet
return distinct(orderedSet)
```